# Gmaps4rails: How to set current user location on map by default in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I've a ***property search bar*** in my app on which the user search for the properties in a city and the locations of the properties are populated on a map using ***Gmaps4rails*** gem. The city names in search bar are ***auto-populated*** by ***typeahead.js***

Everything is good. I get the markings of the locations of on map. But my problem is, the map just show a ***gray image*** or a ***blue image*** on ***not*** entering any city name. Below are the images of the maps on both cases.

***Case 1:*** When city name is given.

[image]

***Case 2:*** When city name is not given.

[image]

How can I modify my code to display the ***current user location*** on map in ***case 2 without disturbing case 1***?

Below is my code.

## view

```
<script src="/assets/typeahead.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="/assets/typeahead-addresspicker.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<!-- for search input END -->

<!-- for MAP -->
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<!-- for MAP END -->

<%= form_tag search_path, :method => :get do %>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm" id="The-Basics">

    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], class: 'form-control typeahead input-sm', id: 'pac-input', :placeholder => 'Enter City, State or Zip!', :autofocus => true %>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
       <%= submit_tag "Go", :name => nil, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm', id: '', data: { no_turbolink: true } %>
   </span>
 </div>
<% end %>

----other content here------

<!-- Gmaps -->
  <div id="rightCol">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Gmaps End -->

<script type="text/javascript">
//google maps
handler = Gmaps.build('Google',
  {
    markers: {
      clusterer: {
        gridSize: 10, maxZoom:15
      }
    }
  });

handler.buildMap({
    provider: {
      disableDefaultUI: false
      // pass in other Google Maps API options here
    },
    internal: {
      id: 'map-canvas'
    }
  },
  function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);

    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(9);
    handler.map.centerOn;
  }
);

// AUTO COMPLETE FOR SEARCH

// mobile address picker
var addressPicker = new AddressPicker({
  autocompleteService: {
    types: ['(cities)'], 
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'US' }
    }
  }
);

$('#pac-input').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'description',
  source: addressPicker.ttAdapter()
});

//  address picker main
var addressPicker = new AddressPicker({
  autocompleteService: {
    types: ['(cities)'], 
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'US' }
    }
  }
);

$('#pac-input2').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'description',
  source: addressPicker.ttAdapter()
});

// AUTO COMPLETE FOR SEARCH END
```

## controller

```
def search
@properties = Property.search_available_coming(params[:available_coming]).where(property_active: true).order(property_city: :asc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@properties) do |property, marker|

    marker.lat property.latitude
    marker.lng property.longitude
    marker.picture({
        "url"    => view_context.image_path("Orange-House-Icon.png"),
        "width"  => 50,
        "height" => 50
         })
    marker.infowindow  render_to_string( partial: 'layouts/mapinfo', locals: { property: property.id })
    marker.title "i'm the title"
end
end
```

Comment: So adding current user location breaks the map entirely and you just get a blank canvas with controls? Are the listeners loaded on the markers?

Comment: @ValAsensio No! I didn't added it yet. I get the blank canvas when there is no input from the search bar. My question is how to modify my code to show current user location on map instead of blank canvas.

Comment: Okay. I see, so if the user does not enter a search city you want to use their current location as the search city. That makes sense. This is just a thought. I know with apps you have to request permission to use auto location services. Typically a pop-up comes up and says "App is requesting your location..." If you say no, then their maps go to some default location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do as follows:

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@properties) do |property, marker|
    marker.lat property.latitude
    marker.lng property.longitude
    marker.picture({
        "url"    => view_context.image_path("Orange-House-Icon.png"),
        "width"  => 50,
        "height" => 50
         })
    marker.infowindow  render_to_string( partial: 'layouts/mapinfo', locals: { property: property.id })
    marker.title "i'm the title"
end
if @hash.empty?
  @hash.push({
    lat: current_user.latitude,
    lng: current_user.longitude
  })
end
```

---

Btw, would be great to rename `@hash` to `@array`

Comment: Can you change the zoom?